# I'm confused about the flow of $_POST[] variables and regular variables

Tags: php, forms, session, post

I have a simple form I created, and in it I have the following checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="test">
```

*Note: this form is being submitted to itself.*

Above the form, I have the following PHP:

```
if (empty($_POST['test'])) {
    $thevalue = 0;
} else {
    $thevalue = 1;
}
var_dump($thevalue);
```

When I process the form, I get what I would expect. If I check the box and submit, I get `int(1)` if I leave it unchecked I get `int(0)`.

---

In the first line of my PHP code, I wanted to replace `$_POST['test']` with some simple variable.

So I added the following line above my code:

`$simplevar = $_POST['test']`

I then replaced the condition in my `if statement` to be `empty($simplevar)`

But when I submit the form, I get a `"Notice: Undefined index:"` error message

1. Why is this happening?
2. Assuming it's possible to achieve what I was after (i.e. insert $_POST into $simplevar), how might I go about it?

Thanks in advance for your help!

PS: I may have a follow up to this question, but didn't want to clutter things by jamming it all in here.

Thanks again... oh, and Merry Christmas! ;-)

Comment: It is happening because you assign `$_POST['test']` to a variable before the form is being sent. So you should do instead: `$simplevar = (isset($_POST['test'])) ? $_POST['test'] : null;`. `empty()` checks whether the variable is 0, empty, or not set at all, so when you check the $_POST directly with this function, it is checking whether it is set or not.

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with `$_POST` and everything to do with the crazy way checkboxes work in HTML. The behaviour you're seeing only applies to checkboxes.

Comment: @Abhi Beckert - that is not true. The `test` element is being inserted into `$_POST` superglobal only after the form is being submitted. Therefore, any manipulations on the element which isn't in the `$_POST` array, will generate this error, regardless the type of the input. It has nothing to do with the type of the input.

Comment: See also the manual on [uninitialized variables (and historic reasons)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php#~initialize+variables) and on the meaning of the [E_NOTICE level](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php#errorfunc.constants.errorlevels.e-notice).

Comment: the index 'test' of the post array is not set unless the checkbox is checked, hence the error when trying to access that variable. just use `$simplevar = isset($_POST['test']);`. language constructs such as isset() do not throw an undefined index error as they are checking to see if the index exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because when you don't check the checkbox, the browser does not send any value to server for that control when the form is submitted. Because of this, `$_POST['test']` is not defined, and you tried to use it without a check as to whether it existed, so you get a warning. One of the checks that `empty()` does is to see whether the value is set. So, when you use the `$_POST` keys directly in `empty()`, you don't get an error, but when you try and use it in an assignment without this check, you will get the error.

You can do roughly what you want to do, you just have to change the logic slightly. If you do:

```
$simplevar = !empty($_POST['test']);
// You could also do
// $simplevar = isset($_POST['test']);

if ($simplevar) {
  // The box was checked
} else {
  // The box was not checked
}
```

...it will do what you want without the error. Using this approach, `$simplevar` always holds a boolean indicating whether or not the box was checked.

Comment: Thanks DaveRandom, that's a very elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

When a checkbox is unchecked, it's not added to the `$_POST` array as a key, which is why `$simplevar = $_POST['test']` returns the error you posted. Using `empty()` gets past this problem by `empty()` handling errors better (well, silently at any rate).

You haven't specified whether you get that error when the checkbox is checked or not, but the above explanation is the only one I can give. If you're unsure, try doing `print_r($_POST)` to see what `$_POST` actually contains.

A solution to your problem would be to use a ternary expression to handle the error a little better:

```
$simplevar = isset($_POST['test']) ? 0 : 1;
```

This will assign `0` to `$simplevar` if `$_POST['test']` isn't set (checkbox isn't checked), or `1` otherwise.

---

Do make sure all your form processing code is put inside

```
if(!empty($_POST)) {
    // Code
}
```

So that it's not executed every time the page loads, otherwise your error will show every time.

Answer (score 0):

Checkbox values are only transmitted if the checkbox was checked. This means that unchecked checkboxes won't appear in the `$_POST` array.

A way to suppress the notice from PHP is to use a reference instead of a variable:

```
$simplevar =& $_POST['test'];
if(empty($simplevar)) $thevalue = 1;
else $thevalue = 0;
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback knittle. I'm not really sure what a reference is (relative to a variable). Can you point out where the reference exists in your example?

Comment: @Nathan: The reference is created in the first line (`&`). `$simplevar` is then a reference to `$_POST['test']` and you can use the reference as it was the original variable  (reading and writing)

Answer (score 0):

That's expected behaviour. If you are assigning the variable like this:

```
$simplevar = $_POST['test'];
```

Then the $_POST variable might be absent. The Zend runtime then assigns the `NULL` value, but gives you a useful debug hint, should that not be what you wanted.

When you used [`empty()`](http://php.net/empty) before, the check for variable existence was built in. `empty()` is a language construct. Like `isset()` it's often used to eschew such notices. The cumbersome syntax to emulate such language behaviour is:

```
$simplevar = empty($_POST['test']) ? NULL : $_POST['test'];
```

The language built-in for is:

```
$simplevar = @( $_POST['test'] );
```

Now, I will get roasted for mentioning it. (Using [`@`](http://php.net/) is useful if you want to bring the debug notices back at some point, while the empty and isset constructs eternally suppress them.)

Answer (score 0):

First, you should always check that variables in $_POST, $_REQUEST, and $_GET are set before attempting to use them.  Always handle the condition where they are not set even if you simply output an error.

Because the error is an undefined index it seem the error is in test not being set in $_POST, though that doesn't make a lot of sense.  I would add a check, maybe an echo or var dump to check $_POST.  If it is set the other problem could be an issue with scope.  $_POST is something called a super global which makes it available in any scope.  Variables you set you may need to make global by defining them as such if you want to access them across scopes.